# How to generate an expiry link in rails for edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated a mailer functionality. I need to generate an expiry link on a mail (for the edit page for one of my models). I just need to add the expiry link in the template. How would I do that? Can anyone help me?

In mailer.template

```
<h5>edit startup</h5>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_booking_url(@booking)%>

Messages Mailer
class MessagesMailer < ApplicationMailer
 def send_email(booking_users)
  @booking_users = User.includes(:roles).where(roles: {:id=> 2})
  mail(to: "penny12@gmail.com")
 end
end

To get the booking id I have called this mailer in the booking model
  def booking_email
    @booking = Booking.find(self.id)
    BookingMailer.send_email.deliver
  end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `expiry link in the template` in mailer template?

Comment: What actually want to do? Please elaborate. Do you want to send a link in the email that will expire sometime?

Comment: @Gabbar till now i have created a mailer funct which sends mail to the user to update their profile . I need to send the edit link for them in the mailer template

Comment: @Penny So just add edit link in mailer template. is there any issue for that? please post your mailer template.

Comment: @Gabbar please check i have addded the code. I have added the edit link , but i am to able to fetch the id, it tells Couldn't find Startup with 'id'=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible for AWS attachment url by paperclip using paperclip or carrierwave gem functionality where timestamp token is passed. :D

You can still achieve what you wanted in following way

**Case-1**:  You are mailing link and you want to give access to edit link for 20 (expiry time) min.

When you will mail, set expiry_date column in object as `Time.now + 20.minute` So when he will click then he will get redirected from edit action if he had crossed `expiry_date` datetime column.

**Case-2**: Above case-1 is not your intention & you want to expire user if he is passing expiry time to fill edit form.

So for above, when user click edit url through mail got (set expiry_date to `Time.now + 20.minute`), he will be redirected to edit form. When he will submit form and action `create/update` is called. It will redirect him another page without updating form.

Additional feature & conditions are needed to be added as per your cases.

**Update:** as per asked

1. When user click edit link, in edit action set **expiry_date** to `Time.now + 1.day`
2. In `Update` action, redirect if expiry_date is passed, otherwise update data.
3. When re-trigger mail action, set **expiry_date** to nil.

Above will meet your requirement.

Comment: I am trying to achive case 2. So basically  should I create a DB coulmn as expiry_date , and then set the value to some time and then send the expiry_date in the url

Comment: @Penny Yes :) But when you want to reset expiration for his edit action again? **1.** when he click edit link in mail again or **2.** when you will mail link again ??

Comment: @roy when he click the edit link in the mail , he should have 24HOURS time to edit it , later it should expire. So it should reactivate when we mail the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184257/discussion-between-penny-and-ray).

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna have a link that can be expired, there 2 options.

1) Using JWT token. The benefit is that you don't need to have any additional db column, everything's in the token itself.

Add

```
gem "jwt"
```

to your Gemfile.

This is my token generator:

```
module Tokens
  class Generator < Base
    EXPIRATION_DELAY = 72.hours

    initialize_with expiration_delay: EXPIRATION_DELAY

    def call
      JWT.encode payload, secret, ENCODING 
    end

    private

    def payload
      { exp: expiration_time }
    end

    def expiration_time
      (Time.zone.now + expiration_delay).to_i
    end
  end
end
```

I then simply add this as additional argument to a link I wanna make expireable. 
When the users follows the link, I meet him/her with this in my controller:

```
    before_action :ensure_link_not_expired!

    def ensure_link_not_expired!
      unless params[:token].present? &&
          Tokens::Validator.call(token: params[:token])
        redirect_to tenant_root_path, alert: t(".link_not_available")
      end
    end
```

And the token validator is here:

```
module Tokens
  class Validator < Base
    initialize_with :token

    def call
      decoded_token.present?
    rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature
      false
    end

    def decoded_token
      JWT.decode token, secret, true, algorithm: ENCODING
    end
  end
end
```

ENCODING = "HS256", secret = Rails.application.secret_key_base

2) A column in your db that stores a deadline. As can be intuited, I went with the first approach, but you can just as easily create related db record with a deadline field and just check it. This would play particularly well with nested resources. Pros - you can track the amount of time left, cons - if it's not a nested resource, you'll have to store garbage records in your db and have a task to clean them